# To show that if $x_{n}$ is a convergent sequence, then $x_{n}^{k}$ is also convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So the question has two parts:

If $x_{n}$ is a convergent sequence, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then show:

$x_{n}^{k}$ is also a convergent sequence.

**Question:** This makes intuitive sense for me, but how do I prove it? For some reason, I also feel a little uncomfortable with this idea, and it seems to me that this will not always be true? I am not sure!

Secondly, we also need to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}^{k} = (\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n})^{k}$

Prove using induction.

**Question:** How do I show this part to be true? I don't even know where to begin. Because in induction, don't you need to use the expression from. the $n^{th}$ step, and then do some algebraic manipulations from it to get the $(n+1)^{th}$ step. But in this case, what manipulation can I do? I am not sure because the sequence has not been defined, so I would not know. how to manipulate it!

Also, if my question statement is not clear, please edit it!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you how to use induction?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Yeah, I edited my question a little! Could you give me a hint maybe?

Comment: Use induction on $k$. Can you prove that if $x_n \to x$ then $x_n^2 \to x^2$?

Comment: But isn't it $x_{n}$ on the LHS, and just x on the RHS?

Comment: Also how come we are inducting on k and not on n?

Comment: you can change $f(x) = x^k$ for any continuous function.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by that. Perhaps someone will come along with an answer for you.

Comment: Alternatively, use a relative of the binomial theorem: $a^k-b^k=(a-b)\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a^i b^{k-1-i}$.

Comment: Hint: use the formula $x_n^k-\epsilon=(x_n-\epsilon^{1/k})(\sum_{p=0}^{k-1} x^{p}_n\epsilon^{(k-p-1)/k})$ and the boundness of $x_n$

Comment: I woud like to use induction!

Comment: Then show how to go from $ |x^{k-1}-\epsilon|$ to $|x^{k}-\epsilon|$

Comment: @am301 Can you tell me why you used k-1, and k, and not n+1,  and n?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I can see why you said what you said, but I am not sure how I could prove that in my answer, do you mind posting an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proof by induction:** For $k=1$ we are given that $\{x_n^k\}$ is convergent. Will call this limit $M $ and it is of course equal to $M^1$. We will prove by induction that for an arbitrary power the series of $x_n$ to that power converges to $M$ to the same power.
Assume now that $\{x_n^{k}\}$ converges to $M^k$ and prove that $\{x_n^{k+1}\}$ converges to $M^{k+1}$
We have:
$$|x_n^{k+1}-M^{k+1}|=|x_n^{k+1}-x_nM^k+x_nM^k-M^{k+1}|\le |x_n||x_n^{k}-M^k|+|M|^k|x_n-M|
$$
Now $x_n$ is bound by some bound $B$ since the series converges. Thus for a given arbitrary small $\epsilon>0$ we can choose $n_1$ such that for $n>n_1$,  $|x_n^{k}-M^k|\lt \epsilon/(2B)$ and $n_2$ such that for $n>n_2$,  $|x_n-M|\lt \epsilon/(2|M|^k)$ and it follows that for $n>\max(n_1,n_2)$ we have:
$$|x_n^{k+1}-M^{k+1}|\lt\epsilon$$

Comment: Can you tell me why you could say that $x_{n}^{k} - M^{k}$ can also be bounded?

Comment: It is not simply bounded but rather - I can make $x_n^k$ as close as I need to $M^k$ (and the abs value of the difference is as small as I need), becasue of the assumption of the induction that $x_n^k$ converges to $M^k$

Comment: Oh, totally forgot about that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, assume the limit of $a_n$ is $L$. Notice that for any $\delta$ there is an $N$ such that if $n\geq N$ we have $|x_n-L| < \delta$, lets use the notation $d=x_n-L$ so for these values of $n$ we have $x_n^k - L^k = (L+d)^k - L = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n d^iL^{n-i}\binom{k}{i}$.

By making $d$ small we can make each summand as small as required. So now we just need to give sufficient conditions for $\delta$, can you take it from here?

Comment: Can you explain how you get the last equality?

Comment: you use newton's formula, and then you cancel the L, which is one of the summands.

Comment: I am not sure how. the proof uses. induction tho?

Comment: What's Newton's formula?